# Back in black sound

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, solos

I'm finally learning back in black from tabs after doing it by ear for a long time.
I've come to the iconic lick during the intro and its tab is given by this almost everywhere:
[image: back in black tab]

For the life of me I can't figure out how to fit in the second pull off from 3 to 0 on the B string. I've listened to the record version over and over again and I just cannot hear the open B.
Is it just played very quickly or missed out when Angus plays it sometimes?

I know the lick starts an extra 1/16th in than what you might first expect and putting in this extra note seems to throw off my playing.

Does anyone have any tips or sympathise with what I'm saying? Input would be really appreciated!

Comment: Bad tab is not unknown

Comment: The tab seems good to me, but I'm not sure how to answer this question, since we already have the tab and we already have a recording of how it sounds.  Maybe writing the beats on top of the tab would help?  Or a video of someone playing it?

Comment: Just gave it a listen on Youtube and I can hear it just fine. Perhaps “doing it by ear for a long time” (apparently incorrectly) has conditioned your ear to hear what it's expecting instead of what’s actually there.

Comment: I can hear it clearly. The more you play and listen critically the more your ear will develop and you’ll be surprised at what you start hearing that you didn’t hear before.

Comment: I can also hear it. The issue for me is how to do a one-tone bend on the G string from fret 2. That is hard!

Comment: Thank-you all, I'll just listen and practice more. I expect I've almost trained myself not to hear it so that might take some undoing.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize that this is an unusual answer format for this site, but I think this is the best way I can illustrate the timing here.  It's not the open B that's played quickly but rather the bend that is quick.